Need a help with CYPD3177
So basically this IC is used to request specific voltage and current options required at any point. You can find a User Manual here.
For changing the output voltage it says in page 21 that you have to update the data memory and you can have a list of PDOs you like. But, it doesn't specify what should be written into these data registers.
Let's say I want a 7 volt output, what should I write?
Update:
I was able to change the list. But I have a new question. In section 5.6 there is a request message where you can request for a voltage you would like.
I tried to send the following message:
0x5002d02d
Which is a PPS 7.2V 2.25A request
and the following is my waveform

But the output voltage of the charger won't change. Can anyone help me with that?

What is the model of the charger? The answer Does USB power delivery support arbitrary voltages? contains So, apparently the adjustable voltage power supply supports USB power delivery version 3.0 whereas the cheaper power supplies support only older versions of USB power delivery.. I.e. the charge may not support Programmable Power Supply (PPS) Charging Models. The requested voltage of 7.2V is not one of the Fixed Voltage Power Ranges of 5V, 9V, 15V, 20V, 28V, 36V or 48V.

@GhesterGillon The charger does support PPS because when I connect a charger I can see that the phone requests and I also can see that the charger sends ACCEPT messages and changes its output voltage.

The user manual linked in the question has references to Power Delivery (PD) Specification. E.g,:

Section 3.7 Summary of Registers has:

Refer to the PD specification for message format.


Section 4.7 CURRENT_PDO has:

Refer to the Power Delivery specification for details on how to interpret the bits in this field.
Refer to Chapter 6.4 of the PD 2.0 or 3.0 specifications for
defails on how to interpret the bits in a PDO.



The USB Implementers Forum USB Power Delivery page has a download for the USB Power Delivery Specification.
The USB Power Delivery Specification defines the format of a 32-bit Power Delivery Object (PDO) where:

Voltage is specified in 50 mV units, in 10 bit fields.
Current is specified in 10 mA units, in 10 bit fields.
Power is specified in 250 mW units, in 10 bit fields.

E.g. the Universal Serial Bus Power Delivery Specification Revision: 2.0 has:


Let's say I want a 7 volt output, what should I write?

With a voltage using 50 mV units, the encoding for a 7 volt output is 7 / 0.05 = 140 decimal or 0010001100 in binary in the 10-bit part of a PDO.
This answer doesn't define the complete message which needs to be written to the CYPD3177 registers, but by referring to the USB Power Delivery Specification you should be able construct the required PDOs.

Thank you for your response. It worked

Hi I've updated my question. Can you check it out and tell me your opinion

@MohsenRazzaghi I have had a look at the updated question, but am not sure why the output of the charger voltage won't change. Suggest you ask a new question, and possibly include a link to this question for reference. Doing that may help to find someone who knows the solution.

@GhesterGillon I'll try and do that do you think the command sent via I2C is correct?
